# Model prediction gives stochastic inputs - Predictive Control

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, model-predictive-control

I have a discrete state space model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$
$$y(k) = Cx(k)$$

And I'm trying to compute the predicted inputs. The first thing I do is that I fist create the extended observability matrix $\Phi$

$$\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}
CA\\ 
CA^2\\ 
CA^3\\ 
\vdots \\
CA^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then create the lower traingular topelitz matrix
$$\Gamma = \begin{bmatrix}
CB & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CAB & CB & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
CA^2B & CAB & CB & 0 & 0\\ 
 \vdots  & \vdots  &\vdots  & \ddots  & 0 \\ 
CA^{n-2} B& CA^{n-3} B  & CA^{n-4} B & \dots  & CA^{n-j} B 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $j=n$

For SISO-case, as in this case. I compute the predicted inputs signals by using:

$$U = (\Gamma)^{-1}(R-\Phi x)$$

For MIMO case. I need to use this equation:

$$U = (\Gamma^T \Gamma)^{-1}\Gamma^T(R-\Phi x)$$

Where $R$ is my reference vector and $x$ is the initial state. I have matlab code for that.

```
function [U] = predict (A, B, C, x, N, r)

  ## Find matrix
  PHI = phiMat(A, C, N);
  GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N);
  U = inv(GAMMA'*GAMMA)*GAMMA'*(repmat(r, N, 1) -PHI*x);
endfunction

function PHI = phiMat(A, C, N)

  ## Create the special Observabillity matrix
  PHI = [];
  for i = 1:N
    PHI = vertcat(PHI, C*A^i);
  endfor

endfunction

function GAMMA = gammaMat(A, B, C, N)

  ## Create the lower triangular toeplitz matrix
  GAMMA = [];
  for i = 1:N
    GAMMA = horzcat(GAMMA, vertcat(zeros((i-1)*size(C*A*B, 1), size(C*A*B, 2)),cabMat(A, B, C, N-i+1)));
  endfor

endfunction

function CAB = cabMat(A, B, C, N)

  ## Create the column for the GAMMA matrix
  CAB = [];
  for i = 0:N-1
    CAB = vertcat(CAB, C*A^i*B);
  endfor

endfunction
```

If I have a state space model, discrete with sample time $h=0.5$.

```
A =

   0.89559   0.37735
  -0.37735   0.51825

B =

   0.10441
   0.37735

C =

   1   0
```

When I run this code above. I get this result if I choose $N = 40$

```
   239.4510
  -301.5661
   301.1320
  -208.4868
   222.4277
  -141.9374
   166.1560
   -94.3562
   125.9231
   -60.3368
    97.1576
   -36.0137
    76.5909
   -18.6233
    61.8862
    -6.1896
    51.3728
     2.7002
    43.8559
     9.0562
    38.4815
    13.6006
    34.6389
    16.8497
    31.8916
    19.1727
    29.9273
    20.8336
    28.5229
    22.0211
    27.5188
    22.8702
    26.8009
    23.4772
    26.2876
    23.9113
    25.9206
    24.2216
    25.6582
    24.4434
```

The correct input signals that tracks the reference is 25. So the algorithm computes correct at last. But when I heard prediction, I was told that I should select the first value of the input signals, not the last one. The first value is `239.4510` and the last value is `24.4434`.

**Questions:**

- I'm I wrong according to prediction that I should use a lower triangular toeplitz matrix?
- Should prediction, by solving linear least squares, looks like this? In this case, I think I need to select the last value.
- If I have a model with a pole equals 1, e.g integration. How would this affect this prediction?

For Model Predictive Control by using a QP-solver, then I can use the first value. But it this case...no.

**EDIT:**

Here is a simulation when we say that the input signals cannot be $ u < 0$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not calculated the formulation by myself. But, I can certainly tell you that you should use the head of $\boldsymbol{U}$ instead of its tail.

Using the tail of $\boldsymbol{U}$ is definitely wrong. Look at the trend of the optimal control inputs. They start shrinking. The system looks stable. But, if you read the inputs upside-down then the system's input is growing (with oscillation). That's scary and looks unstable.

Ignore the the number `25`. Simulate the system as it is and then see how the system behaves.

Comment: Head = first number and tail = last number ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, exactly.

Comment: Bur if I use the first number, the dynamical system is going to looks that it's has shaked a lot. If I use the last number, then the system is going to following the reference very smooth.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, You cannot judge a signal without a simulation. A high oscillation at the end of the prediction horizon is a very bad sign. So, that theory is not going to solve anything. If you want to reduce oscillation at the beginning of prediction horizon, penalize $\Delta u$. Example at this [IEEE conf paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7844292).

Comment: You men regularization? Can you explain how? :)

Comment: Updated my question with an image.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, sorry for the late response. I do not get what you mean by regularization. I meant that in addition to the error and actuation input, you can add the actuation input changes to the cost function. This makes the system reluctant to quick changes.

Comment: can you show how?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, any component you penalize, is expected to decrease.